# c# .net iterating twice a list in a inner and outer loop - local copy or reference?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, iteration

Hallo everyone,

i have a list of nodes ListNode and i want to draw a line between two nodes if there is an edge / link between them. My approach so far is:

```
public void drawGraphInBIM(ref BIM bim)
{
    foreach (Node nodeOuter in ListNode)
    {
        foreach (Node nodeInner in ListNode)
        {
            if (areNodesLinked(nodeOuter, nodeInner))
            {
                bim.drawPolygon(nodeOuter.XYZ, nodeInner.XYZ);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am wandering how the if there is a local copy of ListNode for each loop or is there just a reference and nodeOuter and nodeInner are operating on the same ListNode?

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Cheers,

Dawit

Comment: Slightly vague question... Are you asking for a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Yes, my approach is enough for small sets of nodes but if the sets get larger, it is slow.

Comment: Could you describe the ListNode a bit more, and maybe include the `areNodesLinked` method also (at least pseudo)? I.e. what does edge/link mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same ListNode. No local copies are made of reference types.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same ListNode collection.  You are not copying it.

The reason you're seeing this slow down is because you're current algorithm is O(N^2).  It's going to do N^2 iterations for N items, so as your collection grows, the algorithm slows down exponentially.